# gtk_widget_draw() alternative for gtkmm3

Tags: c++, gtkmm, gtk3

I am lookng for a way of rendering some gtk widget container to pixbuf for later use in drag'n'drop icon image using gtkmm3.

The correct way in native gtk3 to do this is, as far i researched, - usage of gtk_widget_draw() on supplied cairo surface.

The creation of this surface is not an issue, however the call to gtk_widget_draw() itself is.

Only place where it mentioned directly in gtkmm-3.4.2 sources is Gtk::Widget::draw() function (widget.cc:310), which is declared as `protected'.

So my question is: how do i properly perform such task (rendering widget to pixbuf) in gtkmm3?

At this point i see two options:

- Subclass Gtk::Widget to provide public interface to protected draw() function
- Extract gobj* instance from Gtk::Widget and call native Gtk's  gtk_widget_draw() on this instance.

The question is: which way is preferable and why? Or maybe there are some other [better] ways to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `GtkOffscreenWindow` to gather a pixbuf of your widget, from the [docs](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/3.0/classGtk_1_1OffscreenWindow.html#_details) :

> The idea is to take a widget and manually set the state of it, add it
>   to an OffscreenWindow and then retrieve the snapshot as a Gdk::Pixbuf.

and the function:

```
Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Pixbuf> Gtk::OffscreenWindow::get_pixbuf  (       )   
Retrieves a snapshot of the contained widget in the form of a Gdk::Pixbuf.
```

You can also gather some example code (in python) and extra tips, from this related question:

[How to draw any GTK widget on top of Cairo surface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944441/how-to-draw-any-gtk-widget-on-top-of-cairo-surface)